# Get data from console to form c# help? very small app

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a console app to a form I got the form part showing up correctly working but can't figure out how to make the program get its data from the form instead of the console any suggestions?

Console Application

```
namespace doomsday
{
    public class doomsday
    {


       private string firstName;

        public string GetName()
        {
            return this.firstName;
        }//end method GetName

    public doomsday()
    {
       Console.Write(" what is your first name: ");
       this.firstName = Console.ReadLine();


    }// end default constructor

    public string DisplayGreeting()
    {
        return "Hello, " + this.GetName();
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        doomsday hello = new doomsday();

        Console.WriteLine(hello.DisplayGreeting());

        Console.ReadLine();

       Application.Run(new Form1());


    }
```

Form Application

```
namespace doomsday
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }


    }
}
```

[Form http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6995/capturembq.jpg](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/6995/capturembq.jpg)

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is this some sort of homework? 2) Do you *really* use all versions of C# at the same time?

Comment: It's a program that we didn't get to complete in class and I would like to know how to finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Change private string firstName;
```

to

```
public string firstName;



namespace doomsday
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
       public void whenTextbox1LoseFocus {
            var greet = new doomsday();
            greet.firstname = textBox1.Text;
            textbox2.text = greet.DisplayGreeting()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but the label isn't displaying the greeting suggestions?

Comment: I used your method and found that the form needed a button and inside that buttons click event I placed the greeting code.

Comment: yes, this was just psudo code i wrote, you need to an event handler for either the lost focus or button click

Answer (score 3):

In the Visual Studio form designer, add a button to your form. Double-click the button to add an event handler for the button's Click event. Inside the body of this new method you can access the Text property of the text box. For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    textBox2.Text = "Hello, " + name;
}
```

Comment: How would this retrieve the greeting from the application? the purpose of this program is how to take an existing program and add a GUI to it in this case a form that gets all of its data from the console application.

Comment: the button click event was not totally dismissed and thanks to your input I came up with a solution. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure wether i get you on this, but if you want to pass the entries from the console to the form you need to have a public property on the form.

```
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.theDay = doomsday;
    Application.Run(form);
```

On the `Form1` just offer a Property like this:

```
public doomsday theDay { get; set; }
```

Comment: this could possibly be another way of achieving what I needed but I have not tested it. thanks for the response